# Process leaked file descriptors error on JENKINS

Tags: file, jenkins, process, file-descriptor

I am getting this error when I configured a job to do stop and start of tomcat server:

**Process leaked file descriptors. See http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Spawning+processes+from+build for more information**

When i googled it, i got a recommended solution as `set BUILD_ID=dontKillMe`
Is this the exact solution?
If yes, where do I need to set BUILD_ID? Inside ant/post build script?
Can anyone please clarify this?

Answer (score 16):

Yes, creating fake `BUILD_ID` for process tells Jenkins to ignore this process during detection spawned processes, so this process will be not killed after finishing job.

Usage: Enter `BUILD_ID=dontKillMe` before your command, for example into `Execute shell` build step:

```
 BUILD_ID=dontKillMe nohup ./yourStartScript.sh &
```

Note: See also [nohup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup)

Comment: it doesn't work for me within a build step... I believe it should be environment variable

Comment: @Vytalyi I added export BUILD_ID=dontKillMe and it worked for me.

Comment: what should be written for windows? and where ?

Comment: `set BUILD_ID=dontKillMe nohup start yourFIle.bat`
just add that as one line

Answer (score 13):

By default, *Jenkins* will kill all the spawned process at the completion of build.

To override this, you need to create environment variable `BUILD_ID`.

Go to *Jenkins* -> *Manage Jenkins* -> *Configure System*.

Now under *Global properties* section, under *Environment variables*, click on **ADD** button to add new *Environment variable*.
Give `name=BUILD_ID` and `value=allow_to_run_as_daemon start_my_service` 
Click on save button. And you are done.

Now the spawn process will continue to execute even after the build got completed.

Comment: Beautifully worked for a long-running Angular build

Comment: Thanks its works for me in windows and running long bat file

Answer (score 6):

Add this line as a JAVA_ARGS argument when you start your jenkins server (I put mine on /etc/default/jenkins in my Ubuntu box)

```
-Dhudson.util.ProcessTree.disable=true
```

And you're done

Comment: The feature is in place to prevent accidental process leak from builds. Turning it off entirely because of one job is unnecessarily dangerous.

Answer (score 3):

You are calling a command from Jenkins that spawns another process -
the *tomcat-start* command ends, but its child-process is still running
(this is the actual tomcat web-server you attempted to start).

Jenkins sometimes identifies this situation as a possible problem,
but [*the page you have mentioned*](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Spawning+processes+from+build) also explains how to solve it
(in short: Don't start *tomcat* from Jenkins unless you know how).

Answer (score 1):

Tried different suggestions but none of the options worked for me. Finally I switched to previous version of jenkins and it worked. I switched from 2.3 to 1.581 and it worked.