# Jenkins why to start tomcat

Tags: jenkins

What does this command actually do in jenkins build?

Windows Batch Command:

```
start bash ./startTomcat.sh
```

I see many xml files in tomcat folder after the build is over and the build fails....

Comment: In what Jenkins build?

Comment: I dont get your question

Comment: starttomcat is added to the script while configuring a project...why is it added??

Comment: Windows batch command while configuring the project

Comment: Your question is not clear!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues here:

- You are not supposed to start tomcat from within a Jenkins-job
  (see also here **[Process leaked file descriptors error on JENKINS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17031704/1390251)**).
- Tomcat is started as a unix command, while you try to run it from a Windows command - this will never work.