# Process leaked file descriptors error when triggering builds

Tags: jenkins

I have the following error when running a Jenkins task

```
Process leaked file descriptors
```

After reading this post [Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17024441/process-leaked-file-descriptors-error-on-jenkins)

I ended up understanding the problem (I think). I have a build which triggers many tasks. It can for example trigger 4 builds. However, sometimes when one dies, the other dies. I guess it's because of the link that exist between the parent and childs builds like explained there [Jenkins site](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Spawning+processes+from+build)

**The solution however is with command lines and I don't use a command line to trigger my build.**

Is there a way to have a similar solution when triggering a build with the "`Trigger/call builds on other projects`" action.