# Jenkins plugin to copy files to windows server

Tags: jenkins, plugins, jenkins-plugins

I have a situation where in I need to copy set of files to a windows server through Jenkins. I see a lot of Jenkins plugins that will do this kind of job through ssh but not in my case. Jenkins is also hosted in a windows server and end server is also a windows, so I believe ssh is not an option. Any plugin available in the market to get the job done or writing our requirements in powershell/MSDos script is the only option?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

just execute a bat command  with the following

```
copy C:\localfile.bak \\remotemachine\c$\Path\remotefile.bak
```

in the Using the Execute Windows batch command option in the build Step

[How to run bat file in jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48145057/how-to-run-bat-file-in-jenkins?rq=1)