# Error "$ cmd /c call C:\Windows\TEMP\jenkins6446000872510816227.bat The syntax of the command is incorrect."

Tags: jenkins, jmeter

Error "$ cmd /c call C:\Windows\TEMP\jenkins6446000872510816227.bat The syntax of the command is incorrect." while executing job for running JMeter test in Jenkins
Going to TEMP folder there was no jenkins6446000872510816227.bat file error aswell. What could be teh issue and what is the solution for this?

Expecting my job build be SUCESS but it is a failure due to this error

Comment: As in the answer, "double check the syntax of your "Execute Windows batch command" section of the job.". You have a syntax error within your command step. The TEMP\jenkins*.bat are temporary wrapper files for Jenkins to execute the steps. They disappear when Jenkins finishes the step (regardless pass or fail).

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't have sufficient amount of details so we cannot troubleshoot your issue.

1. It's possible to [run JMeter script in command-line non-GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) like:

   ```
   c:\apps\jmeter\bin\jmeter.bat -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl
   ```
2. It's possible to [run Windows batch scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48145057/how-to-run-bat-file-in-jenkins) in Jenkins

   [image]

If it doesn't work for you first check that you can run JMeter test without issues in command-line non-GUI mode on the Jenkins build agent and then double check the syntax of your "Execute Windows batch command" section of the job.

More information: [The Complete Guide to Continuous Integration With Jenkins](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/continuous-integration-jenkins)