# Job randomly fails when executing a shell script on Jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins

I have a jenkins server running on Ubuntu 16.04.2 x64 but recently the jobs started to fail randomly when a shell script is executed. I can execute the script manually on the server and it works but when jenkins executes then it fails for these reasons:

**Fail 1**

```
JavaProcess leaked file descriptors. See https://jenkins.io/redirect/troubleshooting/process-leaked-file-descriptors for more information
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
```

**Fail 2**

```
# gradle script that downloads some jars..
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/pegdown/pegdown/1.6.0/pegdown-1.6.0.jar
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Skipped archiving because build is not successful
```

It's not always the same jar that fails to get downloaded in **Fail 2**.

I have tried to update jenkins to latest version (2.164.2) but still same problem.

I have tried the solutions mentioned in 
[Process leaked file descriptors error on JENKINS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17024441/process-leaked-file-descriptors-error-on-jenkins)
for **Fail 1** but no success, still fails the same way.

---

**Update 1**

I have localized the problem in my shell script to this part:

```
# Run script in docker container
chmod +x tmp.sh
docker run --entrypoint=/bin/bash -v $(pwd):/src --workdir=/build mydocker/myimage -c "/src/tmp.sh"
rm -f tmp.sh
```

So when docker is executing my tmp.sh through Jenkins "Execute shell" it fails randomly.

Log from docker `journalctl -u docker.service`

```
May 21 10:33:23 jenkins dockerd[1332]: time="2019-05-21T10:33:23.886024261Z" level=error msg="attach: stdout: write unix /var/run/docker.sock->@: write: broken pipe"
May 21 10:33:25 jenkins dockerd[1332]: time="2019-05-21T10:33:25.186663914Z" level=error msg="attach: stderr: write unix /var/run/docker.sock->@: write: broken pipe"
May 21 10:33:25 jenkins dockerd[1332]: time="2019-05-21T10:33:25.186715731Z" level=error msg="attach failed with error: write unix /var/run/docker.sock->@: write: broken pipe"
```

Log from docker container `docker container logs cranky_cori`

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 38.273 secs

This build could be faster, please consider using the Gradle Daemon: https://docs.gradle.org/2.14/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
```

**Conclusion**

Pipe to stdout and stderr gets broken and jenkins reports this as failed build but the docker container logs shows that docker continued executing and successfully finished my gradle script.

Comment: try to run this command manually  and check for errors

Comment: @yarin as it says in my description - I've tried running the command manually and it doesn't fail

Comment: did you try as a jenkins user?

Comment: thanks @yarin, I tried as jenkins user and root - it still works when running it manually.

Comment: @yarin I have updated with some more information, see update1. Do you have any idea of what might cause the problem now? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After unsuccessfully finding the cause of my issue I though of upgrading my OS, and boy I was lucky!

**Configuration not working**

```
Ubuntu 16.04.2 x64
----------------------------
- Docker version 17.03.1-ce
- Jenkins 2.64.2
NOR 
- Docker version 18.09.6
- Jenkins 2.64.2
- Jenkins 2.64.3
```

**After upgrading Ubuntu this worked for me**

```
Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS 
----------------------------
- Docker version 18.09.6
- Jenkins 2.64.3
```